# Quantifying the universal approximation theorem

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, optimization, approximation, polynomial

Let $m\geq 1$ be an integer and $F\in \mathbb{R}[x_1, \dots, x_m]$ be a polynomial. I want to approximate $F$ on the unit hypercube $[0, 1]^m$ by a (possibly multilayer) feedforward neural network. The activation function is $\mathrm{tanh}$ for all the connections.

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be a real number. If I want the approximation to deviate from $F$ by less than $\varepsilon$ in the $L^2$ norm what is the smallest possible number of non-zero weights?

It is kind of stupid to approximate a function that is known to be polynomial by a neural network but I just wanted to get more quantitative insight into the universal approximation theorem (and polynomials seem to be the most accessible class of functions).

Comment: I do not know a lot about neural networks but your problem does not seem completely specified. For example the zero-polynomial would probably require less non-zero weights than a non-zero one. Furthermore you would probably like to bound the degree. And what would be the data the approximation is based on?

Comment: your problem is not completely specified, you need to specify the (fixed) domain where the approximation must stay into limits. convergence to $F$ is not uniform